# R apriori rules of specific columns

Tags: r, data-mining, rules, apriori

I have a following dataset:

```
from | to | time_period
house | shop | evening
residential building | transportation | night
....
food | public building | morning
```

I use Apriori algorithm:

```
rules = apriori(data, parameter=list(support=0.01, confidence=0.5));
inspect(head(sort(rules, by="lift"),10));
```

And it produces me following output:
   lhs                            rhs                            support confidence     lift

```
1  {from=residential building,                                                              
    to=food}                   => {time_period=night}         0.01398601  0.5882353 2.285806
2  {from=entertainment}        => {time_period=evening}       0.02517483  0.5294118 2.188031
3  {to=entertainment}          => {time_period=evening}       0.01678322  0.5217391 2.156321
4  {to=food,                                                                                
    time_period=night}         => {from=residential building} 0.01398601  1.0000000 1.735437
5  {from=food,                                                                              
    to=food}                   => {time_period=daytime}       0.01538462  0.8461538 1.689944
6  {from=public building,                                                                   
    to=food}                   => {time_period=daytime}       0.01958042  0.8235294 1.644758
7  {to=residential building,                                                                
    time_period=night}         => {from=residential building} 0.19580420  0.9459459 1.641629
8  {time_period=night}         => {from=residential building} 0.24195804  0.9402174 1.631688
9  {from=education,                                                                         
    to=residential building}   => {time_period=daytime}       0.01538462  0.7857143 1.569234
10 {from=food,                                                                              
    to=residential building}   => {time_period=daytime}       0.02237762  0.7619048 1.521681
```

It generates all kinds of rules, but this is not exactly I want. I want to have only rules of

```
{from, time_period} => {to}
```

For example, `{from=food, time_period=daytime} => {to=residential building}.` I am not interested in any other rules except `{from, time_period} => {to}`, which means that rules like `{from, to} => {time_period}` or `{time_period} => {from}` or any other does not interest me.

How can I do that?

Comment: It is not clear what the expected output is.  Can you be a bit more specific

Comment: @akrun Added the example.

Comment: Have to converted to a `transactions` object before doing the `apriori`

Comment: Can you explain it in more details? I do not get it

Comment: If you look at the `?apriori`, the `data(Adult)` is already a transactions dataset.  I wonder if you are using `data.frame` directly or not.

Comment: Yes, I am using data.frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **filter the results**, and keep only those rules that you are interested in.

The expensive part of Apriori is finding the frequent itemsets, and you cannot save much there. You do also need the frequency of itemsets without `to`.

Generating the actual rules afterwards is cheap; so you might just as well generate all of them, then only keep those with a `to` on the right.

However, given that you only have three columns, and one is your desired outcome, **you don't need association rule mining at all**.

Apriori and these are beneficial when you have *long* rules, because they can avoid redundant computations. Apriori starts getting interesting at length 3 the earliest.

Here, Apriori will not be more efficient than just enumerating all `from -> to`, `time_period -> to` and `from + time_period -> to` combinations and computing the desired quality each.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same situation where i needed to find relationship with only two attributes where the data frame had 11 attributes in total. Using apriori generated roughly 7000 rules.

Try something like below. It worked for me.

rules = apriori(**select(data,c("from","time_period","to")**), parameter=list(support=0.01, confidence=0.5));

Input for the apriori function is only the columns of interest. I extracted columns using **select** in **dplyr** package.